# Trying to declare a lambda function inside command parameter for the button but it doesn't work(Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I'm trying to enter a function with parameters without calling it by using lambda but I bump into an error, do you know why?

Here's the function:

```
accountName = ""
accountPassword = ""

def switchScreenState(newState,username,password):
    screenState = newState
    if username != None & password != None:
        accountName = username
        accountPassword = password
```

All I'm trying to do is to change the accountName and accountPassword values for my code.

Here's where I'm trying to write it down:

```
hashtagB = tk.Button(mainWindow, text="Automation by Hashtags", bg="blue", width=20, command=lambda _: switchScreenState("hashtag selection",usernameEntry.get(),passwordEntry.get()))
hashtagB.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.40, anchor="center")
```

And here's from where I retrieve the new values:

```
usernameEntry = tk.Entry(mainWindow, width=30)
usernameCanvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.20, anchor="center")

passwordEntry = tk.Entry(mainWindow, width=30)
passwordEntry.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.32, anchor="center")
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Change `lambda _: ...` to `lambda: ...`.

Comment: didn't notice, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting error (in future please post the traceback in the question too) is that tkinter's button requires `command` to be function of no arguments. So drop the underscore in your code.

```
hashtagB = tk.Button(mainWindow, text="Automation by Hashtags", bg="blue", width=20, command=lambda: switchScreenState("hashtag selection", usernameEntry.get(), passwordEntry.get()))
```

Also note that it's better to check for None the following way and use `and` when you don't mean bit operations:

```
if username is not None and password is not None:
```